# QTextEdit does not print text

Tags: python, printing, pyqt4, qtextedit

I am using PyQt4 to design the interface of my Python program. Now I want to print something in the QTextEdit called "answere", but it does not print anything. I tested that the text is there (see `print(n_text)`), and it is.

Short overview of the program: a question will be entered, and the program should answer it.

Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import database
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

class RasPi(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('main_window.ui')
        self.ui.setWindowTitle('Fragen an den Raspi')

        self.ui.show()

        self.connect(self.ui.ask, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.reading)

    def reading(self):

        txt = str(self.ui.question.text()).lower()
        database.Base().searching(txt)

    def answere(self, text):

        n_text = QtCore.QString(text)
        print(n_text)
        self.ui.answere.append(n_text)

if __name__=='__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    raspi=RasPi()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT

Here is the second class called Database.py.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
import raspi

class Base(object):

    def searching(self, txt):


        if txt == '':
            n_txt = "Du hast keine Frage gestellt"

        else:

            if txt == ("modell"):
                n_txt = "Bei mir handelt es sich um einen Raspberry Pi B, im allgemeinen werde ich aber auch RasPi B genannt."

            elif txt == ("hardware"):
                n_txt = "CPU: ARM1176JZF-S\nArbeitsspeicher: 512MB\nGPU: Broadcom Dual Core VideoCore IV, OpenGL-ES 1.1/2.0, Full HD 1080p30\nAudio: HDMI (digital); 3,5-mm-Klinkenstecker (analog)\nNetzwerk: 10/100-MBit-Ethernet\nStromversorgung: 5V;Micro-USB-Anschluss (Micro-USB-B)\nSonstiges: 2x USB"

            elif txt == ("software"):
                n_txt = "Ich laufe auf einer Abwandlung von GNU/Linux."

            elif txt == ("passwort"):
                n_txt = "Warum sollte ich dir mein Passwort verraten?\nDas Standart-Passwort ist allerdings raspberry."

            elif txt == ("start"):
                n_txt = "Um das Userinterface zu starten, gib einfach im Terminal startx ein. Ansonsten kann man natürlich auch den Terminal selbst benutzen"

            elif txt == ("daten") or txt == "gewicht":
                n_txt = "Meine Größe beträgt 93x63,5x20. Mit diesen Abmessungen passe ich sogar in einen Geldbeutel\nIch wiege auch nur 40 Gramm."

            elif txt == "konkurenz" or txt == "alternative":
                n_txt = "Es gibt noch den Banana Pi, das Pandaboard, das Cubieboard und viele mehr."

            elif txt == "geschichte" or txt == "lebenslauf": 
                n_txt = "Der Raspberry Pi wurde von der britschischen Raspberry Pi Foundation entwickelt. Er kam anfang 2015 auf den Markt; sein großer Markterfolg wird teils als Revival des bis dahin weitgehend bedeutungslosen Heimcomputers zum Programmieren und Experimentieren angesehen."

            elif txt == "hintergrund": 
                n_txt = "Der RasPi wurde von der Stiftung mit dem Ziel entwickelt, jungen Menschen den Erwerb von Programmier- und Hardwarekenntnissen zu erleichtern."

            elif txt == "nutzen":
                n_txt = "Man kann einen RasPi wie einen ganz normalen Computer nutzen, das einzige worauf zu achten ist, dass die Hardware weniger Leistung bringt. Sie ist vergleichbar mit einem Rechner von 1990.\nHier noch ein paar Nutzungsbeispiele:\n Heimserver\ntragbarer Computer\nWetterstation\nusw."

            elif txt == "kosten":
                n_txt = "Der Preis für einen Raspberry Pi liegt zwischen 20 und 35 USD, dabei kommt es ganz auf das Modell und dessen Ausstattung an."

            else:
                n_txt = "Leider kann ich deine Frage nicht beantworten."

        raspi.RasPi().answere(n_txt)
```

Comment: Is there some code missing? There is nothing that calls `answere()` in the code you've shown.

Comment: Yes, there is a second class called Database, i will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Base.searching` method, you have this line:

```
    raspi.RasPi().answere(n_txt)
```

This will create a new, temporary, instance of `Raspi` class, which will just get deleted once the `answere()` method returns.

What you need to do is try to keep the code in the `database` module completely separate from the gui code in the `raspi` module.

The database module should look like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Base(object):    
    def searching(self, txt):
        if txt == '':
            n_txt = "Du hast keine Frage gestellt"
        else:
            if txt == ("modell"):
            ...
        return n_txt
```

and the `raspi` module should look like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import database
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

class RasPi(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('main_window.ui')
        self.ui.setWindowTitle('Fragen an den Raspi')
        self.ui.show()
        self.connect(self.ui.ask, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.reading)
        # keep an instance of the database
        self.db = database.Base()

    def reading(self)
        txt = unicode(self.ui.question.text()).lower()
        # get the answer from the database
        ans = self.db.searching(txt)
        # show the answer
        self.answere(ans)

    def answere(self, text):
        self.ui.answere.append(text)

if __name__=='__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    raspi = RasPi()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```